# MVC3 App under IIS 5.1 doesnt load CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-5

I have MVC3 app. When I run it under ASP.NET Development Server from Visual Studio, everything is fine. **But, when I run it under IIS, the CSS is not loading at all**.

Any manipulation with permission didnt help, even if I sent full access to everyone for the whole solution folder. I have IIS 5.1 on Windows XP. I enabled MVC3 support (.*) in IIS, the application runs fine, except CSS is not loading for some reason.

When running under IIS - doesnt pick up static content.

Actually, no static content work - not css, not javascript files from the Script folders.
And this is weird, since I have another MVC3 app with exactly same Web.Config and exactly the same VirtuialDirectory configuration that works just fine, all JS and CSS are loaded correctly.

And I dont see any difference, except one works, another one -doesnt ;(

**UPDATE**

After playing with creating default MVC3 applications in different folder and with different names, I found that the problem ONLY happens when the application name contains DOT :)

Something like "MyCompany.MyApplication" WILL not work correctly under IIS 5.1.

If I call it just "MyApplication1" - everything works ! Go guess....

Comment: if you put the URL of the CSS file in the browser, do you get some error ?

Comment: Yes, I get "Page not found", dont know why

Comment: Could it be you are using a rewrite module which is not present in the IIS installation ?

Comment: I am not sure what rewrite module is.
This is basically the default MVC3 app that is created by VS template.

Comment: this will be an issue in your Global.asax file I would imagine. Can you post this?

Comment: Everything is a default when you select Create new project - MVC3 application. The application runs fine from VS under ASP.NET Development Server. The problem is when it runs under IIS only.

Comment: Ok, I will post Global.asax, but I dont knwo why you need it...

Comment: Here is the link: http://i.imgur.com/LUpOS.png

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be UrlScan fault: I changed "AllowDotInPath" option in the "UrlScan.ini" to 0 and voila! Here is the reference:
www.iis.net/learn/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference